# Problem to save data from a form to the session

Tags: django

I am trying to save the data from a form to the session but it seems that it's not the right datatype.

I have tried model_to_dict and cleaned as it is working fine for my other form that takes similar data in entry but it didn't work.

```
class ActivitiesForm(forms.Form):
    activity = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Select your activities', queryset=Activity.objects.all())
    target_group = forms.ChoiceField(label='Who is the report destined to?', choices=OutputOutcomeImpact.TARGETGROUP)


class Activities(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'blog/activities.html'
    context = {'title': 'Activities selection page'}
    def get(self, request):
        form_act = ActivitiesForm()
        form_act.fields['activity'].queryset = Activity.objects.filter(categories__sectors__name=request.session['sector']['name'])
        self.context['form_act']=form_act
        return render(request,self.template_name, self.context)
    def post(self,request):
        form_act = ActivitiesForm(request.POST)
        if form_act.is_valid():
            print(form_act.is_valid(),form_act.cleaned_data['activity'],type(form_act.cleaned_data['activity']),type(model_to_dict(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'])),form_act['activity'])
            request.session['activity'] = model_to_dict(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'])
            request.session['target_group'] = model_to_dict(form_act.cleaned_data['target_group'])
            return redirect('/about', self.context)
```

Here's the type of data that I get from the print and the error:

```
True Municipal waste incineration <class 'blog.models.Activity'> <class 'dict'> <select name="activity" required id="id_activity">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="Municipal waste incineration" selected>Municipal waste incineration</option>

  <option value="Plastic upcycling">Plastic upcycling</option>

</select>
Internal Server Error: /activities/
.
.
.
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is with `target_group`. Its value should be string because it is coming from `ChoiceField`. So you don't need to use `model_to_dict` for that.

```
request.session['target_group'] = form_act.cleaned_data['target_group']
```

Comment: Ok I can print form_act.cleaned_data['target_group'] it's  of type string so it's fine, the problem comes from activity.

Comment: can you please share the codes for `OutputOutcomeImpact.TARGETGROUP`

Comment: target_group is working fine with your code. But print(model_to_dict(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'])) returns __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Comment: print(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'],type(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'])) 
  returns  Municipal waste incineration <class 'blog.models.Activity'>

Comment: When you run print, it returns the value from `def __str__(self)` method, where will have the code for `Municipal waste incineration <class 'blog.models.Activity'>`. But `model_to_dict(form_act.cleaned_data['activity'])` should work, because from print I am seeing `form_act.cleaned_data['activity']` is returning an instance of Activity model. Try printing the value of `pk` by `form_act.cleaned_data['activity'].pk`, and please see if its printing the right instance or not

Comment: Ok I have found an error in the instance Municipal waste incineration that probably comes from my last model change, I think the first problem is solved now thanks.